# Directory Browser in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using Directory Browser used in   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DirectoryBrowsing.aspx . When I am running the application on localhost, UNC path is working fine. When I deploy the application in IIS UNC(Shared drives/Folders) is not working. It cannot find the Shared Drive and folders?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to mind is permissions - check that the AppPool/Identity you are using for IIS has access rights to these UNC shares.

Comment: i am using IIS6 ...How can we configure permissions

Comment: Definitely agree, this has to be permissions. User *should* be able to add Machine\IIS AppPool\DefaultWebSite (or named as you have created) to the ACLs... Given that it's IIS6 you're probably going to need to make IIS app pool user be Network Service, and then you should be able to add Machine\Network Service to the permissions

Comment: Check the permissions for your network shared folder. See if you see the App pool identity has access to this folder.